# Gambian in Italy wants to visit UK

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, gambian-citizens

My wife is a naturalised UK citizen from Gambia. Her brother is 17 and in Italy with a Permesso di Soggiorno.

- Would he need a visa or would he be able to join us in the UK immediately?
- If he arrived in the UK with the residence permit and a Gambian passport and evidence that they are brother and sister would he be allowed in?
- Would he be allowed to board an aircraft in Italy without a visa stamp in his passport?

We are trying to do it quickly before he turns 18 in July.

Comment: Do you mean he wants to move to the UK and live there?

Comment: Just to visit initially

Answer (score 16):

He still needs a visit visa. He's a visa national. The Italian residence permit and UK citizen sister won't change that.

Edit to add: visa processing times in Rome should be less than 15 days for uncomplicated cases.